# How can I insert elements to the array alphabetically?

Tags: java

I have a data structure. It is working with array and I want to insert elements to the array alphabetically. I did this but it doesnt work. It is in sortedInsert method. I cut out where the other methods are.  How can I do it?

````
    private Product[] arr;
    private int size;
    private int sortCost;
    public ProductArray(int len) {
        arr = new Product[len];
        size = 0;
    }
    
     void sortedInsert(Product pr) {
         for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
             if(arr[i].getName().compareTo(pr.getName()) < 0) {
                 size++;
                 for(int j = i; j < size; j++) {
                     
                     arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                     
                 }
                 arr[i] = pr;
                 
             }
         }
     } 
    
    
} ```

And this is my Product class: :


class Product {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int price;
    public Product(String name_, String description_, int price_) {
            // constructor
            name = name_;
            description = description_;
            price = price_;
        }
public void displayProduct() {
            System.out.print(" Product name: " + name);
            System.out.print(", Description: " + description);
            System.out.println(", Price: " + price);
        }
public String getName(){
            return name;
}
}
````

Answer (score 2):

This is an *Array* and static in size. in order to do what you are trying you will have to allocate a new array, with a length of oldLength + 1. Then you can search for the first element (n) which is alphabetically located after the new element and System.arraycopy all elements before n, then insert the new one and then arraycopy all elements from (n) to the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

As a previous answer mentioned, an array in Java has a fixed size, so you would need to re-allocate the array to make room for a new element.

Probably the easiest answer here is to use one of Java's Collection classes which provide automatic reallocation instead, like an ArrayList (add an element, then sort the list with Collections.sort()), or maybe a TreeSet (which would automatically maintain proper sort order when you add an item)

Comment: I should'nt use array list or something on this question. I have to use just array. I did it using arrayList but it is not accepted by my instructor.

Comment: Ok, so when asking a question like this (i.e. homework), where there are constraints on what you are allowed to do (e.g. "I must use an array"), you might want to mention that up-front.

Comment: Yes u are right. I should have specified. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

First the solution with what we have:

```
void sortedInsert(Product product) {
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 0, size, product,
                    Comparator.comparing(Product::getName));
    if (index >= 0) { // Found
        System.out.println("There already exists a product with that name");
        arr[index] = product;
    } else { // Not found, ~(insert_position);
        index = ~index;
        System.arraycopy(arr, index, arr, index + 1, size - index);
        // Shifts to the right.
        ++size;
        arr[index] = product;
    }
}
```

There is a usefull binary search returning the position of the found one, or ~position (= -position - 1; < 0) for the insert position.

`System.arraycopy` is an old copying of an array slice.

A lambda (anonymous function) is used to get then name gettter - for comparison.

Better would be to have a Map from name to Product. SortedMap's exist, like a TreeMap.

```
private final SortedMap<String, Product> allProductsByName =
        new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Product::getName));

Product anyOldPr = allProductsByName.put(pr.getName(), pr);
if (anyOldPr != null) oops;
```

Comment: Sure, a decent data structure is what would be used in 'real life'.  But the OP is learning and evidently still doesn't quite understand basic things like arrays.  I'd say it is necessary to  work with the fundamentals of the subject first, in order to develop understanding.

Comment: @user16632363 that's why I did not add increasing the array with Arrays.copyOf. You mean `binarySearch` already is too sophisticated? BTW the map stuff is there to show the shortness of how it can be done, Labdas are maybe too advanced, but oh so usefull.

Comment: Binary search is not too sophisticated, but I think one ought to implement it oneself at least once, **if** the aim is to understand programming.

Comment: @user16632363 is entirely right. For instance that "binary" stands for splitting array ranges in half, repeatedly. [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) [Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/)

Comment: The bitwise complement of the index is a bit non-obvious for a beginner.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek in the comment "explained." It is hard to start from scratch. TreeSet for instance would be better with a Comparable Product and such. BTW I find the code of the OP not bad at all.